# Continuously run a piece of code in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm making an Android game, and I'll need a continuously running thread for basically everything.
Now, however, I'm making the main menu (I always start simple, I'm new to coding), and I want an image to float across the main screen. I know how I could code that (determining the starting location, changing it), but I don't know how to run such a piece of code continuously (outside the UI thread).

P.S.: Please be easy on me. I know I'm probably missing something obvious, but I have virtually no Java experience at all.

Comment: come on! start reading a book, or doing some google!

Comment: I did, but I couldn't find what I was looking for, or in a way I could use it the way I wanted to. Again, novice programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** Create a **Non-UI thread, with Handler**. And run it within **Controlled loop** using a boolean variable. Handler will be helpful in putting the output of the Non-Ui thread on the
Ui thread.

**2.** You can use an **AsyncTask**, introduced in android to synchronize the UI with Non-Ui thread.

Comment: Right. A handler. Explains why I couldn't find what I was searching for, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
while(check){//your code}
```

In run method you can put put a globle boolean variable to check the condition.